# Connecting Commerce module with registered users

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a site that forces users to register before they can make any purchase, But I can't figure out a way to get the information from the registered users on my site and use it in my commerce module customer profile, so people don't have to enter their information again while making a purchase.

Using:
Drupal 7 Commerce Module

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce Addressbook](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook) could be useful for you.

Comment: Commerce Addressbook is in fact a good choice, but it doesn't solve this specific problem. There is no way for Commerce to know what fields you may have set up for your users, in order to get that information transferred into Commerce customer profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Commerce Extra](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_extra)

> **Feature/improvement overview**
>
> - Improve checkout by pre-populating customer profile information's    addressfield. Needs an address field for user entity. See also
>     Commerce Addressbook for similiar functionality.
> - Add extra step where user may login, but doesn't require it.
> - Improve quantity field by wrapping it with decrease/increase button    links.